# Android Image stored in ImageView not deleted after implementing delete button

Tags: android, imageview

when I clicked delete button it deleted for a second and it came back, it seems that its not deleting permanently (which what I wish to do in case user do not wish to upload photo anymore)

```
public void btnDeletePhotoClicked(View v) {
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSpecimenPhoto);
    iv.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

Declared:

1. XML 
   btnDeletePhotoClicked -> ImageView Button (OnClick)
2. imgSpecimenPhoto -> ImageView

Any experts on this?

Comment: You refresh the view later? Another solution you can try is, setVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: Does `iv.setImageResource(0);` instead of `iv.setImageDrawable(null);` work?

Comment: @Marcus Hey I tried that code, it doesn't even attempt to delete at all.. thanks anyways! :) *P.S. my code now worked, but sometimes it doesn't delete.

Comment: Hi @Braindead, I tried your code, it does work in deleting, but I'm not able to add image from camera there afterwards.. *P.S. Sometimes my code able to delete sometimes it just delete awhile and comes back.. Thanks for your help :)